# ng-repeat commented showing in internet explorer while working fine on others angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
[
   {
      "user_id":95507,
      "social_id":null,
      "type":2,
      "spr_id":0,
      "link_confirmed":null,
      "sp":[
         {
            "id":"131556",
            "user_id":"95507",
            "spr_id":"1"
         },
         {
            "id":"131557",
            "user_id":"95507",
            "spr_id":"2"
         },
         {
            "id":"131558",
            "user_id":"95507",
            "spr_id":"3"
         },
         {
            "id":"131559",
            "user_id":"95507",
            "spr_id":"4"
         },
         {
            "id":"131560",
            "user_id":"95507",
            "spr_id":"5"
         },
         {
            "id":"131561",
            "user_id":"95507",
            "spr_id":"7"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "user_id":95509,
      "social_id":null,
      "type":3,
      "spr_id":1,
      "link_confirmed":null,
      "sp":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "user_id":95510,
      "social_id":null,
      "type":3,
      "spr_id":1,
      "link_confirmed":null,
      "sp":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "user_id":95512,
      "social_id":null,
      "type":2,
      "spr_id":0,
      "link_confirmed":null,
      "sp":[
         {
            "id":"131569",
            "user_id":"95512",
            "spr_id":"1"
         },
         {
            "id":"131570",
            "user_id":"95512",
            "spr_id":"2"
         },
         {
            "id":"131571",
            "user_id":"95512",
            "spr_id":"3"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "user_id":95513,
      "social_id":null,
      "type":3,
      "spr_id":1,
      "link_confirmed":null,
      "sp":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "user_id":96276,
      "social_id":null,
      "type":3,
      "spr_id":1,
      "link_confirmed":null,
      "sp":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "user_id":96277,
      "social_id":null,
      "type":3,
      "spr_id":1,
      "link_confirmed":null,
      "sp":[

      ]
   }
]
```

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="profile in profile_users | filter: { link_confirmed : '!' } | filter: filterExpressions track by $index">
    <td>{{ profile.user_id }}</td>
    <span ng-repeat="spd in profile.sp track by $index">
        {{ (profile.type == 2) ? ($index >= 0 && profile.sp.length - 1 &&  $last-1) ? sp[spd.spr_id] + ", " : sp[spd.spr_id] : '' }}
    </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

`ng-repeat` commented showing in internet explorer while working fine on others AngularJS don't know why I did not changes does not work for me. Please assist me how can I fix this, thanks in advance

Updated the json formatted for better understanding please take a look now let me know where i'm wrong

Note this is only in Internet explorere nothing seems wrong with other browser

Comment: Please check first part of the code, structure seems to be wrong

Comment: which one part..?

Comment: @IgnacioAra JSON is correct. Please be more specific.

Comment: @Justin :can u try to create a plunkr and see if you can replicate the issue for us to refer. Cant help much if the code is not shared as it shouldn't happen in the first place

Comment: I think you're missing something in parent or not allowing accessible profile_users here please post in fiddle..